# If $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$, then what is wrong about the following factor chain approach to proving $p \neq 5$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, factoring, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

Suppose that $n = p^k m^2$ is an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

That $n$ is perfect essentially means that
$$\sigma(p^k)\sigma(m^2)=\sigma(p^k m^2)=\sigma(n)=2n=2p^k m^2,$$
where $\sigma(x)$ is the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  In terms of the *abundancy index* $I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$, we have
$$I(p^k)I(m^2)=I(p^k m^2)=2.$$
Note that both $\sigma$ and $I$ are [multiplicative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function).  In particular, note that when $a$ divides $b$ (denoted by $a \mid b$), then $I(a) \leq I(b)$.

Now, since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, it is easy to prove (Exercise!) that
$$(p+1) \mid \sigma(p^k).$$

In fact, furthermore, since $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, this shows that
$$\frac{p+1}{2} \mid \frac{\sigma(p^k)}{2} \mid n.$$

In particular, this shows that, if $p=5$, then $3 \mid n$.  This implies that $3^2 \mid m^2$.

By employing the factor chain method (see, for example, this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/414232)), we have the following:
$$3^2 || m^2 \implies \sigma(3^2) = 13 \mid m^2 \implies {13}^2 \mid m^2$$
$${13}^2 || m^2 \implies \sigma({13}^2) = 3\times{61} = 183 \mid m^2 \implies {61}^2 \mid m^2$$
$${61}^2 || m^2 \implies \sigma({61}^2) = 3\times{13}\times{97} = 3783 \mid m^2 \implies {97}^2 \mid m^2$$
$${97}^2 || m^2 \implies \sigma({97}^2) = 3\times{3169} = 9507 \mid m^2 \implies {3169}^2 \mid m^2$$
$${3169}^2 || m^2 \implies \sigma({3169}^2) = 3\times{3348577} = 10045731 \mid m^2 \implies {3348577}^2 \mid m^2$$

Now, test:
$$1.60723 \approx \frac{100916741461563}{62789076915421} = I({3}^2)I({13}^2)I({61}^2)I({97}^2)I({3169}^2)I({3348577}^2) \leq I(m^2) \leq \frac{2}{I(p)} = \frac{2p}{p+1} = \frac{5}{3},$$
whence there is no contradiction.

(Here are the [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28DivisorSigma%5B1%2C3%5E2%5D%2F%283%5E2%29%29*%28DivisorSigma%5B1%2C%2813%29%5E2%5D%2F%28%2813%29%5E2%29%29*%28DivisorSigma%5B1%2C%2861%29%5E2%5D%2F%28%2861%29%5E2%29%29*%28DivisorSigma%5B1%2C%2897%29%5E2%5D%2F%28%2897%29%5E2%29%29*%28DivisorSigma%5B1%2C%283169%29%5E2%5D%2F%28%283169%29%5E2%29%29) [computations](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2830137193%2F18750973%29*%28DivisorSigma%5B1%2C%283348577%29%5E2%5D%2F%28%283348577%29%5E2%29%29).)

**QUESTIONS**

> *(1)* Am I doing the factor chain method properly?  That is, when I encounter consequent factors which are already part of assumed factors, should I ignore the succeeding (consequent) factors?   (For example, notice that I got $3$ and $13$ as consequent factors from $\sigma({61}^2)$, and that I ignored them, and only used the prime $97$, since $3$ is an assumed prime factor from the very beginning and $13$ is a consequent factor of $\sigma({3}^2)$ from the second line.)
>
> *(2)* Or should I incorporate / keep track of **all consequent factors** in the abundancy index computations, as they occur?

Comment: Would the (quick) downvoter care to explain his/her vote please?  As it is, I am totally clueless.  Some form of feedback (hopefully constructive) would go a long way in improving future questions/posts.